# how can i reduce document reads in firestore from my react app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i am a complete beginner with firestore and i don't really know how i can connect with the state in my react app, and i don't even know if that's the problem. i started my app for like three second with about less than 20 docs in the database. i go to look at my usage and it says i did 6.1k document reads. i am just learning and i wanted to do it in the free plan so im trying to keep the reads under 50k.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvHx2.png).

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../components/css/general.css";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import {
  setDoc,
  collection,
  doc,
  getDocs,
  addDoc,
  deleteDoc,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  NavLink,
  Route,
  Routes,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addtodo } from "../features/addtodoslice.js";
import Todocard from "../components/todocard";

const firebaseConfig = {
  // nah
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const colref = collection(db, "todos");
const docsos = getDocs(colref).then((snap) => {
  return snap.docs;
});

const Home = () => {
  const todos = useSelector((state) => state.addtodo.todos);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [fieldvalue, setfieldvalue] = useState("");
  const [datefieldvalue, setdatefieldvalue] = useState("");
  const [colorfieldvalue, setcolorfieldvalue] = useState("#000");
  const [showform, setshowform] = useState(false);
  const [showbutton, setshowbutton] = useState(true);
  const docref = doc(db, "todos", "p7bpRUw4EDHQXh8KbgaV");
  const colref = collection(db, "todos");
  const [docs, setdocs] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div className="cont">
      <h1>Welcome to the Home page</h1>
      <p>This is the home page of your application.</p>

      {showform ? (
        <form
          className="addtodoform card"
          action="#"
          onSubmit={(event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            // addDoc(colref, {
            //   name: fieldvalue,
            //   color: colorfieldvalue,
            //   datetime: datefieldvalue,
            // });
            console.log(docsos);
            setshowform(false);
            setshowbutton(true);
            setfieldvalue("");
            setdatefieldvalue("");
            setcolorfieldvalue("#000");
          }}
        >
          <input
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
            className="addtodoinput"
            name="todotitle"
            type="text"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setfieldvalue(e.target.value);
            }}
            value={fieldvalue}
            placeholder="Title"
            required
          />
          <div className="groupallabove">
            <input
              className="colorpicker"
              type="color"
              onChange={(e) => colorfieldonchange(e.target.value)}
            />
            <div className="groupall">
              <input
                name="duedate"
                type="datetime-local"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setdatefieldvalue(e.target.value);
                  console.log(e.target.value);
                }}
                required
              />
              <input name="submit" type="submit" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      ) : (
        <div></div>
      )}

      {showbutton ? (
        <button
          className="blackbutton"
          onClick={() => {
            setshowform(true);
            setshowbutton(false);
          }}
        >
          Add Task
        </button>
      ) : (
        <div></div>
      )}

      <div className="todolist">
        {docs.map((todo) => (
          <Todocard
            name={todo.data().name}
            date={todo.data().datetime}
            color={todo.data().color}
            id={todo.id}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  function colorfieldonchange(e) {
    setcolorfieldvalue(e);
    console.log(e);
  }
};

export default Home;
```

i tried to put the function that gets the docs out of the component so maybe it doesn't refresh whenever the state changes.

Comment: You can use [Firebase emulator suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) to test this and save your expensive reads and writes as those will be done locally.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by moving the `getDocs` function into a `useEffect` hook. I think I ran into the very obvious mistake where the docs would get read and put into the state, so the state re-rendered the component, so it would read the docs again and set the state again, and on and on.